# In the ms chart - winform, I want the RangeBar graph to be centered on the x-axis

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

In the ms chart, I want the RangeBar graph to be centered on the x-axis.

Only number 5 is in the middle and the other numbers are not middle children. I want to center this.

This happens when you adjust the PixelPointWidth.
When set to 1, it goes to the center, but the thickness is too small.

```
private void AddSerise(StartAndEndTime startAndEndTime)
    {
        int z = 0;
        if (searchDeviceId.Contains(startAndEndTime.DeviceID))
        {
            z = searchDeviceId.IndexOf(startAndEndTime.DeviceID);
        }
        else
        {
            Series series2 = new Series(startAndEndTime.DeviceID);
            mainChart.Series.Add(series2);
            searchDeviceId.Add(startAndEndTime.DeviceID);
            z = searchDeviceId.IndexOf(startAndEndTime.DeviceID);

        }

        mainChart.Series[startAndEndTime.DeviceID].ChartArea = "MainArea";
        // mainChart.Series[startAndEndTime.DeviceID].Label = startAndEndTime.DeviceID;
        //mainChart.Series[startAndEndTime.DeviceID].IsVisibleInLegend = true;
        mainChart.Series[startAndEndTime.DeviceID].ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeBar;
        mainChart.Series[startAndEndTime.DeviceID].AxisLabel = z.ToString();
        mainChart.Series[startAndEndTime.DeviceID].LegendText = startAndEndTime.DeviceID + "." + startAndEndTime.EventID;
        mainChart.Series[startAndEndTime.DeviceID].Points.AddXY(z, startAndEndTime.startTime.ToOADate(), startAndEndTime.endTime.ToOADate());
        mainChart.Series[startAndEndTime.DeviceID]["PixelPointWidth"] = "50";
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Bars (and Columns) are always grouped by series and the group as a whole is centered around the values.

Comment: What if I don't want to group?